# Container size changes when scrollbar appears

Tags: html, css

I have a sidenav which shows the sidenav on hover. Its hidden in other states. When the scrollbar appears, the content width on the sidenav reduces. You can see that with the `.active` class background. The background doesn't span the entire width when the scroll bar appears and leaves. Is there a way I can make the background take the entire width when the scrollbar disappears.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidenav {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidenav:hover {
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.active {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidenav">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, assumenda! Impedit culpa veniam id, aut sit rerum nisi, saepe dolorum tempore at velit nam explicabo fugiat consectetur mollitia nulla blanditiis.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried z-index?

Comment: The problem is Chrome-specific. Works in FF, IE11 & Edge. [Consider putting the scrollbar outside the div](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+scrollbar+outside+div&oq=css+scrollbar+out).